# bigquery - slow query on a small table

Tags: google-bigquery

I've created a table with 3 columns (id:integer,name:string,short_name:string) and 3 rows. If I execute

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.table
```

it takes 1.9s. Is that normal?

```
Job Id: zentinel-datawarehouse:bquijob_64fd3936_159d0c17b7b
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is normal. BigQuery is a solution for big data so it's not well suited for queries that run under the seconds threshold.

On the other hand, you will also see queries processing terabytes of data in a few seconds as well.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I've thought that. But I couldn't find a doc with the explanation